# how import created template in a local typesafe activator instance

Tags: templates, typesafe-activator

I have created a typesafe activator template. Before publishing to the public I want to test that template in a  local running typesafe activator instance. In the docs a only found a way for public publishing.

What I have to do to make my template available to my local typesafe activator instance so I can create new applications on the base of my imported template ?

Best regards

Andreas